# Instant Rails no Rakefile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-vista

I just installed InstantRails on my PC running Vista.
When trying to update some files, I run into this error:

...\rails_apps>rake rails:update
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

where rails_apps is in the directory where I extracted InstantRails.  Am I not in the correct directory?  One book says to do this in the app directory, but I can't seem to locate it.

I have also tried making an app, but I get the following error:

rails_apps>rails demo

```
 C:/Users/Tio/Documents/Rails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:379:in 
report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: rake(0.7.3 not >= 0.8.3) (Gem::Lo
adError)
        from C:/Users/Tio/Documents/Rails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygem
s.rb:311:inactivate'
        from C:/Users/Tio/Documents/Rails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygem
s.rb:337:in activate'
        from C:/Users/Tio/Documents/Rails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygem
s.rb:336:ineach'
        from C:/Users/Tio/Documents/Rails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygem
s.rb:336:in activate'
        from C:/Users/Tio/Documents/Rails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygem
s.rb:65:inactive_gem_with_options'
        from C:/Users/Tio/Documents/Rails/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygem
s.rb:50:in `gem'
        from C:/Users/Tio/Documents/Rails/ruby/bin/rails:18
```

This was what led me to try the rake rails:update
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Instant Rails but it sounds like you don't have an app created yet. In your rails_apps directory run

```
rails <app_name>
```

where app_name is the name of the app you want to create. This command will generate a new Rails app for you. The Rake commands can then be run from inside this new directory (this is the app directory that the book you mention is referring to).

Comment: theIV is right. Try 'gem update --system', that should get you the latest gems.

Answer (score 0):

The second error is saying that you need a newer version of `rake`. Try `gem install rake`—sorry, I don't know if gem installation is different on Windows.